# Automate meeting invitations and responses

Tags: exchangewebservices

Using Exchange Web Services, I want to achieve the following:

The management board holds many meetings. These meetings are mandatory for all board members, and they are scheduled by the secretary, which also has full access to the calendar of all board members, but not to their email, which additionally is pushed by ActiveSync to the board members' phones.

I now have to automate, using EWS Managed API, creation of such meetings, complete with all Invitations and Accepts. No invitation/accept email should be received by any of the board members on any device, yet they should all have the meetings in their calendar, each looking like a normal Outlook meeting.

Is this possible, or would I have to put simple appointments into all calendars?

I have not yet found a way to create a meeting without sending invitations, while accepting these unsent invitations. Neither did I find a way to flag the invitation as "do not sync to device", to balk exchange from pushing these invitations out.

Answer (score 1):

Short of sitting on each member's Inbox using Push or Streaming notifications, and then trying to simulate the acceptance--which IMHO would be fraught with peril, not to mention hundreds of LOC--I think just putting the appts on their calendars is the best way, especially because the secretary already has full access.